# Wmic command not found while running cmd through runas command

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, administrator, runas, wmic

I open a normal cmd and ranned wmic in two different ways

Method 1:

Open cmd

Run the command :

runas /noprofile /user:AAA cmd

Note : aa as administrator privilege

It opened another cmd with header as (command prompt (running as aaa))

In that command I ran

Wmic

It throws message saying program not found

Method 2:

Right click cmd and run as administrator

Give wmic

It works

Note : I use windows 7 basic

In both cases I am having system32 as my current directory

Comment: Did you read the help context, "runas /?" ?

Comment: @GiaRui yes , first I used administrator as my username but none of the password works ,

Comment: Then I used user with administrative privileges ,

Comment: @GiaRui how can I get Administrator password for my windows 7 , I have only one user account iny system and that is aaa

Comment: Did you try to run "net user" in cmd ? Or you might check on the graphical user interface "start-user accounts" if your account is standard or administrator.